# Date to milliseconds and back to date in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, time

I am taking the current time, in UTC, and putting it in nanaoseconds and then I need to take the nanoseconds and go back to a date in local time.

I am able to do get the time to nanoseconds and then back to a date string but the time gets convoluted when I go from a string to date.

```
//Date to milliseconds
func currentTimeInMiliseconds() -> Int! {
    let currentDate = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone!
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate as Date))
    let nowDouble = date!.timeIntervalSince1970
    return Int(nowDouble*1000)
}

//Milliseconds to date
extension Int {
    func dateFromMilliseconds(format:String) -> Date {
        let date : NSDate! = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:Double(self) / 1000.0)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
    
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        return ( formatter.date( from: timeStamp ) )!
    }
}
```

The timestamp is correct but the date returned isn't.

Comment: You are converting a date to a string and right back to the same date which seems to be useless. Once again, what is the used date format `format`? Actually `Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)` can replace the entire function. `NSDate` is just a double value without considering a time zone

Comment: You seem to use *nanoseconds* in your question when you appear to mean *milliseconds*. There are 1 million nanoseconds in a millisecond, so it's not an inconsequential mistake.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

I don't understand why you're doing anything with strings...

```
extension Date {
    var millisecondsSince1970:Int64 {
        Int64((self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0).rounded())
    }
    
    init(milliseconds:Int64) {
        self = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(milliseconds) / 1000)
    }
}


Date().millisecondsSince1970 // 1476889390939
Date(milliseconds: 0) // "Dec 31, 1969, 4:00 PM" (PDT variant of 1970 UTC)
```

Comment: I am doing the string because i need millisecondsSince1970 to be in UTC and init(milliseconds:Int) to be put back in local time.

Comment: Date objects are *always* in UTC. Those values in my example are UTC (note how the description method then renders the UTC epoch beginning in PDT).

Comment: Better to do init(milliseconds:Double) instead of Int or else you will lose the milliseconds when you convert back.

Comment: davis: If I understand correctly, the `timeIntervalSince1970` is a double and therefore has millisecond precision in it. The multiplier and cast are there to convert this into a int.

Comment: @davis It doesn't loose the millisecond precision, but it does loose sub-millisecond precision. Unless you absolutely need to convert the date to an integer, consider using my answer.

Answer (score 56):

As @Travis Solution works but in some cases

`var millisecondsSince1970:Int`  **WILL CAUSE CRASH APPLICATION** ,

with error

> Double value cannot be converted to Int because the result would be greater than Int.max if it occurs **Please update your answer with Int64**

Here is Updated Answer

```
extension Date {
 var millisecondsSince1970:Int64 {
        return Int64((self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0).rounded()) 
        //RESOLVED CRASH HERE
    }

    init(milliseconds:Int) {
        self = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(milliseconds / 1000))
    }
}
```

---

[About Int definitions.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int)

> On 32-bit platforms, Int is the same size as Int32, and on 64-bit platforms, Int is the same size as Int64.

Generally, I encounter this problem in `iPhone 5`, which runs in 32-bit env. New devices run 64-bit env now. Their `Int` will be `Int64`.

Hope it is helpful to someone who also has same problem

Comment: Why would that error happen? Time interval since 1970 is a 32 bit number. At least until we get to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: @DoesData If you see we are multiplying number with 1000. this causes out of the range of Int32

Comment: Some old iOS device run in 32-bit env. It's `Int` is `Int32`. But new iOS device, ex: iPhone 6, it's `Int` is `Int64`. So, 32-bit problem may cause crash in old iOS devices.

Answer (score 17):

@Travis solution is right, but it loses milliseconds when a Date is generated. I have added a line to include the milliseconds into the date:

If you don't need this precision, use the Travis solution because it will be faster.

```
extension Date {

    func toMillis() -> Int64! {
        return Int64(self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }

    init(millis: Int64) {
        self = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(millis / 1000))
        self.addTimeInterval(TimeInterval(Double(millis % 1000) / 1000 ))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 13):

```
//Date to milliseconds
func currentTimeInMiliseconds() -> Int {
    let currentDate = Date()
    let since1970 = currentDate.timeIntervalSince1970
    return Int(since1970 * 1000)
}

//Milliseconds to date
extension Int {
    func dateFromMilliseconds() -> Date {
        return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(self)/1000)
    }
}
```

I removed seemingly useless conversion via string and all those random `!`.

Comment: This would be great but I need currentTimeInMilliseconds to convert the local time to UTC and I need dateFromMilliseconds to convert from UTC to local time

Comment: [Timestamp **is** in UTC already.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdate/1416453-init). > `The number of seconds from the reference date (00:00:00 **UTC** on 1 January 1970)`

Comment: You will not lose millisecond precision, but you will lose sub-millisecond precision. Unless the time interval absolutely needs to be represented as an integer, consider my answer below instead.

Comment: @PeterSchorn, yep, this code in the answer was just a cleaned up version of the code from the question. The question had `Int`, therefore the answer has `Int` too.

Answer (score 3):

```
let dateTimeStamp = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:Double(currentTimeInMiliseconds())/1000)  //UTC time  //YOUR currentTimeInMiliseconds METHOD
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone() 
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle


let strDateSelect = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateTimeStamp)
print("Local Time", strDateSelect) //Local time


let dateFormatter2 = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter2.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as NSTimeZone!
dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let date3 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(strDateSelect)
print("DATE",date3)
```

Answer (score 2):

@Prashant Tukadiya answer works. But if you want to save the value in UserDefaults and then compare it to other date you get yout int64 truncated so it can cause problems. I found a solution.

Swift 4:

You can save int64 as string in UserDefaults:

```
let value: String(Date().millisecondsSince1970)
let stringValue = String(value)
UserDefaults.standard.set(stringValue, forKey: "int64String")
```

Like that you avoid Int truncation.

And then you can recover the original value:

```
let int64String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "int64String")
let originalValue = Int64(int64String!)
```

This allow you to compare it with other date values:

```
let currentTime = Date().millisecondsSince1970
let int64String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "int64String")
let originalValue = Int64(int64String!) ?? 0 

if currentTime < originalValue {
     return false
} else {
     return true
}
```

Hope this helps someone who has same problem

Comment: `Date().millisecondsSince1970` is showing as unresolved

Comment: @javadba try `Date().timeIntervalSince1970`. The return value is a `Double` that represents the number of seconds since 1970 – it is precise to 'sub-millisecond precision'. See here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timeinterval

Comment: @javadba `Date().millisecondsSince1970` is a custom extension in the posts for this question. It's not in Foundation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution in Swift 5/iOS 13.

```
extension Date {
    
    func toMilliseconds() -> Int64 {
        Int64(self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }

    init(milliseconds:Int) {
        self = Date().advanced(by: TimeInterval(integerLiteral: Int64(milliseconds / 1000)))
    }
}
```

This assumes you have calculated the difference between UTC time and local time and adjusted and accounted for in the milliseconds. For that, use `Calendar`.

```
var cal = Calendar.current
cal.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
let difference = cal.compare(dateGiven, to: date, toGranularity: .nanosecond)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Simple one-line code to get time token in UInt64**

```
let time = UInt64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)

print(time) <----- prints time in UInt64
```

Additional tip:

For timestamp with **10 Digit milliseconds since 1970 for API call** then

```
let timeStamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

print(timeStamp) <-- prints current time stamp
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch out if you are going to compare dates after the conversion!

For instance, I got simulator's asset with date as TimeInterval(366144731.9), converted to milliseconds Int64(1344451931900) and back to TimeInterval(366144731.9000001), using

```
func convertToMilli(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval) -> Int64 {
    return Int64(timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
}

func convertMilliToDate(milliseconds: Int64) -> Date {
    return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: (TimeInterval(milliseconds) / 1000))
}
```

I tried to fetch the asset by creationDate and it doesn't find the asset, as you could figure, the numbers are not the same.

I tried multiple solutions to reduce double's decimal precision, like round(interval*1000)/1000, use NSDecimalNumber, etc... with no success.

I ended up fetching by interval -1 < creationDate < interval + 1, instead of creationDate == Interval.

There may be a better solution!?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you absolutely have to convert the date to an integer, consider using a `Double` instead to represent the time interval. After all, this is the type that `timeIntervalSince1970` returns. All of the answers that convert to integers loose sub-millisecond precision, but this solution is much more accurate (although you will still lose some precision due to floating-point imprecision).

````swift
public extension Date {
    
    /// The interval, in milliseconds, between the date value and
    /// 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.
    /// Equivalent to `self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000`.
    var millisecondsSince1970: Double {
        return self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
    }

    /**
     Creates a date value initialized relative to 00:00:00 UTC
     on 1 January 1970 by a given number of **milliseconds**.
     
     equivalent to
     ```
     self.init(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(milliseconds) / 1000)
     ```
     - Parameter millisecondsSince1970: A time interval in milliseconds.
     */
    init(millisecondsSince1970 milliseconds: Double) {
        self.init(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(milliseconds) / 1000)
    }

}
````