# fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because the result would be greater than Int.max

Tags: ios, swift

Getting Issue:

> Double value cannot be converted to Int because the result would be
>   greater than Int.max

While converting date to time Interval

```
 extension Date {
   var millisecondsSince1970:Int {
    return Int((self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0).rounded())
  }

  init(milliseconds:Int) {
    self = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(milliseconds / 
  1000))
 }
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error?

Comment: I don't see any fatal error after implementing your extension. Please elaborate.

Comment: I faced same Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46294917/4601900