# Swift unix timestamp too short

Tags: swift, timestamp

i need to get the current unix timestamp in my IOS app. The expected result should have this length: 1545519600000.
the actual length is 1546194931. Here is my code:

```
   let someDate = Date()

    // convert Date to TimeInterval (typealias for Double)
    let timeInterval = someDate.timeIntervalSince1970

    // convert to Integer
    let myInt = Int(timeInterval)
```

I need an Integer as result.
Thx

Comment: If you want milliseconds then multiply it by 1000 ...

Comment: @Carpsen90:  The given example 1545519600000 is the timestamp of  Dec 22 23:00:00 UTC 2018 in *milliseconds.* – The overflow issue is addressed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46294917/1187415) of the duplicate target.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks