# Best practice to store milliseconds in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my application our backend service sends me `startedTime` parameter as a milliseconds (sample value is 1649576635649). I need to store it in CoreData and I already tried to store in `String` and `Integer64`. There are also other options like `NSNumber, Integer16, Integer32` However I am not sure which one is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I would store it as Date in Core Data

See

[Date to milliseconds and back to date in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134323/date-to-milliseconds-and-back-to-date-in-swift)

for the conversion.

Comment: Why do you think so do you have any specific reason?

Comment: Because it is a Date / Time Date as a parameter and is directly supported by Core Data with alll its features and further operations, formats and protocols.